# java.io.File customized file names

Tags: java

I created a code, it works fine and all, but I wanted the program to generate a .txt file with the results to save it for later use. But I want the program to create different files each time I execute it because I plan to use it once a month (it's for a monthly profit calculation) and save it using the year and month numbers to name the file.

For example:

```
File file = new File("C:\...\YearMonth.txt");
```

But of course the year and month would depend on the `int Year` and `int Month` variables informed previously in the program.

Any ideas? Hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a file meta_data to store info of previous files

So, when you create a new file, you will want to read meta_data file to generate new file name

Hope this could help you

Answer (score 1):

Is it you want?

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year       = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month      = (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);

    String fileName = "profit_"+ month + "_" + year + ".txt";

    File file = new File("C:...\\" + fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using a Stand Alone java Program.
When you want to log the results which are printed in Console use below way

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year       = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month      = (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    String fileName = "Log_"+year"_"+month+".txt"
   File file = new File (fileName);    
   FileOutputStream  fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ps = new PrintStream(fos);  
        System.setOut(ps); // This will write all the console log to a file.
 //when exiting the program or before termination Flush the PrintStream
```

Comment: That's what I thought I should have done but I wasn't sure if that would work! Can I write like this... File file = new File("C:\...\"+fileName); using the code you wrote above?

Comment: Yes You can but better configure the File location.